# not able to ping remote ip from my virtual box having bridged adapter setting

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos-5

my virtual box having environment in the range of 172.18.122.XXX, and remote ip is in range of 153.60.64.XXX, but i am not able to ping it.
My network settings of vm is bridged adapter.
can anyone suggest me the possible changes. I can access the same IP via NAT, but then, i can't access it from putty. So, I want to access it with bridged adapter setting

[ifcfg-eth0 file setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BNHT.png)

Comment: How is the Ip assigned to the virtual machine? Do you use DHCP? Does correctly assign the IP to the virtual machine?

Comment: i). yes, as u can also see the field value BOOTProte = "dhcp" in attached screenshot.  ii) majority of times it assign correctly in 172 series , and if  it assign wrong then , i assign it in 192 range by linux commands